# Reinforcement learning for combining production rules

Tags: reference-request, cognitive-modeling, reinforcement-learning

I'm trying to create a system that learns the Tower of Hanoi puzzle. [The system I'm working off of](http://compneuro.uwaterloo.ca/files/publications/stewart.2011a.pdf) uses a production system (similar to ACT-R), but uses hard-coded production rules. I know that [Neil Taatgen's Primitive Information Processing Elements](http://www.ai.rug.nl/~niels/publications/TaatgenICCM2013.pdf) can be used to combine memory buffers/slots to run a task more efficiently, but is there some method of reinforcement learning that would guide the construction of sets of production rules in a cognitive system?

Note that I've asked a [similar question on the Computer Science StackExchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/45651/combining-production-rules-using-reinforcement-learning), but with more of a reinforcement learning perspective.